# How to call php code with argv via php_shell

Tags: php, arguments, php-7

**I need to call PHP file with argument via php_shell.**

What I did:

```
  $output = shell_exec("php -n -s $script_path/test.php $one $two, $three");

  if($output !=null)
  {
  echo "your file called";
  }else{
  echo "Your file not called";
  }
```

But it's not running the `test.php` file.

Suggest what I missed in this configuration, and I am using PHP-strom. Is there any environment setup?

Comment: can you try using `shell_exec("php-cli...` ?

Comment: @ImAtWar if I add php-cli it goes to else part like "Your file not called".

Comment: does the file exist? what path are you using?

Comment: @ImAtWar yes,,file is there,  I am getting file path form post value($script path) is there issue?

Comment: You can try entering the full path to your php installation, find it with `which php` while in your shell. E.g. `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: @GijsdeJong  I added  /usr/bin/php instead fo php   still same issue

Comment: @Rajkumar - Can you print the string inside shell_exec into a variable and run it independently on the command prompt?